# Trying to resize UITextView to its contentSize. ContentSize is always 30 when it shouldn't be

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a uitextview that I am trying to resize according to the text inside of it. I am using the following code:

```
[self.view addSubview:storyText];
[storyText sizeToFit];
[storyText layoutIfNeeded];
[storyText setScrollEnabled:NO];
CGRect frame = storyText.frame;
frame.size.height = storyText.contentSize.height;
frame.size.width = 280;
storyText.frame = frame;
```

The frame is definitely resizing, but the problem is, it does not resize according to how many  lines there are, but instead always resizes to a height of 30. With an NSLog, I determined that `contentSize` is set to 30 regardless of how many lines there are in the textview. Do I need to manually set contentSize, or will it calculate itself depending on how much space is taken up by the content? If so, why is it always setting itself to 30 here?

update: 
I've tried the following as suggested and it did not work.

```
[storyText setScrollEnabled:NO];
[storyText sizeToFit];
[storyText sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(280,CGFLOAT_MAX)];
[storyText layoutIfNeeded];

CGRect storyFrame = storyText.frame;
storyFrame.size.height = storyText.contentSize.height;
storyFrame.size.width = 280;
storyText.frame = storyFrame;
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try call sizeToFit after [storyText setScrollEnabled:NO]

Comment: That didn't make a difference.

Comment: Then try use `[textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(widthOfView,CGFLOAT_MAX)]`. It works for me

Comment: After `[storyText setScrollEnabled:NO]`.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested (edited the question to show what I put), and it still has not made a difference. thank you for the suggestions however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try use your code. My code:

```
UITextView *txtView = [UITextView new];
txtView.text = @"some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_some_big_text_";
txtView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[c.view addSubview:txtView];

CGSize size = [txtView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(280,CGFLOAT_MAX)];
txtView.frame = CGRectMake(.0f, .0f, size.width, size.height);
```

and I get correct height of textview. Can you try it?